# как создать массив объектов в react native

Tags: react-native

Всем привет у меня такая задача.
Юзер проходит тест, отвечает на вопрос, кликает по кнопке записать вопрос, переходит к следующему вопросу и тд.
Необходимо создать массив объектов в state, и передать его на другой экран чтобы там отобразить, у меня получается создать только просто массив со значениями.
Реализовал это я так:

`<TextInput 
   placeholder={"Ваш ответ"}
   onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}/>`

записываю ответ в state, после по нажатию на button записываю в массив answers.

```
<Button
  title="Ответить"
  onPress={() => this.setState(prevState => ({
  answers: [...prevState.answers, item.question, this.state.text]}))}/>
```

А вот как добавить в массив объект этих значений не могу найти, как это сделать? спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, если у кого-то возникнет подобная проблема, вот решение:

```
<Button
 title="Ответить"
 onPress={() => this.setState(prevState => ({
 answers: 
 [...prevState.answers,{
 question: item.question, 
 answer: this.state.text}]}))}/>
```